# Use batch to convert string to WinSCP session URL

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I'am using batch and WinSCP to connect to a FTP-Server and upload some files automatically. After a recent password change I encountered the problem that the password contains special characters that will not allow me to connect to the server.

The special characters can be found here: [Session URL :: WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url#special)

Converting the forebidden characters shouldn't be a problem in theory. I used the following code to convert a string with a `%` character:

```
setlocal
SET test="Test % test"
set test=%test:%=%25%
echo %test%
```

The output of the script is `=5`.

So there is a problem with the `%`. I tried to escape the `%` with `%%`. Therefore my code looks like this:

```
setlocal
set test="Test %% test"
set test=%test:%%=%%25%
echo %test%
```

The output is `5`.

Is it possible to encode a given string, to fit the requirements of the session URL with batch? How can I encode the string?

Answer (score 1):

Escaping for destination and inside batch are different things,
to keep the single `%` from being interpreted by cmd it has to be doubled.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set test="Test %% test"
set test
set test=!test:%%=%%25!
set test
```

Sample output:

```
test="Test % test"
test="Test %25 test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since WinSCP 5.19, you can use [`-username`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#username) and [`-password`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#password) switches, which do not need any encoding, instead of including the credentials to the session URL.

```
open ftp://example.com/ -username=username -password=password
```